# Download xbox uwp app to desktop

Tags: windows-10, uwp, xbox-one, microsoft-store

I wish to install a UWP app on my laptop (windows 10), but the app is only available to install on Xbox one and I don't have one. I'm aware that some xbox apps won't work on desktop but in that specific case I know it should.
If it matters, the app is Disney+ and as noted [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/disney-needs-release-its-app-windows10), it **does** work on desktop.

I thought about downloading the .MSIX file and installing it by myself just like you can download an apk, but... I couldn't find anyway for doing this.
Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer!

1. Visit microsoft store website
2. Search for the app you wish to install
3. Once you're on the app page, copy the the URL adress
4. Goto https://store.rg-adguard.net/
5. Enter the link you just copied and click the button
6. Download your Msix file for your platform and open it
   **Make sure you download the file that it's name matches the app's name**